# How to get string from text box and display in page in javascript

Tags: javascript, string

I'm a newbie to javascript, i have a function which gets a text box value and returns it back, but I am not able to use the return value outside of the function. I want the function to return a string and display it in the webpage. Below is the code.

```
<%@ page import="java.io.*,java.util.*,java.sql.*"%>
<%@ page import="javax.servlet.http.*,javax.servlet.*" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql" prefix="sql"%>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title> Inventory test </title>
</head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">

function function1(){

     var x = document.getElementById("text1").value;

     if (x.length == ""){
         alert ( "input is empty");
     }else{
         alert ( x + " " + "fine"); 
         return x;
     }
 }

</script>

First name: <input type="text" id="text1" name="text1" autofocus>

<button onclick="function1()"> submit </button>

<p id="p1">p1</p> 


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of returning, just directly assign what you want, for example, use

```
document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = x
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set value of text input to dom element

```
function function1() {
    document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = document.getElementById("text1").value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function function1()
{

 var x = document.getElementById("text1").value;

  if (x.length == "")
   {
    alert ( "input is empty");
   }
    else
   {
     alert ( x + " " + "fine"); 
   document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = x;

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<%@ page import="java.io.*,java.util.*,java.sql.*"%>
<%@ page import="javax.servlet.http.*,javax.servlet.*" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql" prefix="sql"%>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title> Inventory test </title>
</head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">

function function1(){

     var textValue = document.getElementById("text1").value;

     if (x.length == ""){
         alert ( "input is empty");
     }else{
         document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = textValue;
     }
 }

</script>

First name: <input type="text" id="text1" name="text1" autofocus>

<button onclick="function1()"> submit </button>

<p id="p1">p1</p> 


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, I want that function to return a string which I want to send to database server to query I don't want to set it to another object.